# Using Mac OS command 'codesign' in Linux

Tags: linux, macos, code-signing

> The codesign command is used to create, check, and display code signatures, as well as inquire into the
>        dynamic status of signed code in the system.

Is there equivalent of the 'codesign' command in the Linux?

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Linux uses `ELF` while OSX uses `Mach-O` executable file format, so it certainly wouldn't be a very close equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux does not use code signing. There is no equivalent. Signing on Linux is done at the packaging level, not at the executable level. You can sign RPM packages, for example.

Answer (score 6):

As has been said, there's no real equivalent to `codesign`.

However, having said that, `codesign` and it's supporting programs are released under the [Apple Open Source Development model](https://www.apple.com/opensource/).

So, if you fancy digging around with the [codesign code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/security_systemkeychain/security_systemkeychain-55191/src/) then I'm sure there will be many other people interested in the outcome

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer to the question. Once you have gathered some reputation points you will be able to comment on others' questions and answers. Please file an answer only for real answers.

Comment: @cfi I disagree, I think it's an appropriate answer to the question, though I think the question is skating the line between being discrete and being too broad

Answer (score 6):

There is many solution now !!!!

you can check these github projects:

https://github.com/saucelabs/isign

and

https://github.com/zhlynn/zsign

i worked with both and both of them is good enough !
but isign project need some little contribute for serve all your needs but it's work on ios<12 !

zsign is too clean and easy to setup !

i hope this helps you!

**Update:**

zsign working fine with ios 12 currently and i suggest you to use that !

Comment: Is it possible to use zsign to sign applications too? The documentation states only about iOS signing.

Comment: yeah ... you can sign applicaitons from scratch or resign them with the zsign @Panayotis

Comment: thank you for your answer, just to make myself clear: I am talking about signing macos executables, not iOS. There's no need to resign an (unsigned) macOS app.

Comment: @Panayotis I didn't check that on macOs applications ... sorry